# C#: Get size of a soft linked file

Tags: c#, filesize, symlink

I am looking for a simple way to get the size of a softlink file.

The FileInfo class returns 0 bytes everytime.

How can I get the real file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/12/9962359.aspx

> Functions like GetFileAttributes and FindFirstFile, when asked to
> provide information about a symbolic link, returns information about
> the link itself and not the link destination. If you use the
> FindFirstFile function, you can tell that you have a symbolic link
> because the file attributes will have the
> FILE_ATTRIBUTES_REPARSE_POINT flag set, and the dwReserved0 member
> will contain the special value IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK.
>
> Okay, great, so now I know I have a symbolic link, but what if I want information about the link target?
>
> For example, I want to know the size of the link target, its last-modified time, and its name. To
> do this, you open the symbolic link. The I/O manager dereferences the
> symbolic link and gives you a handle to the link destination. You can
> then call functions like GetFileSize, GetFileInformationByHandleEx, or
> GetFinalPathNameByHandle to obtain information about the symbolic link
> target.

Here's some actual code with demo http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/ReparsePointID.aspx

Comment: That looks like much interop work. Maybe I could use `GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`. And than get the other informations with the FileInfo class.

Answer (score 1):

This works on symlinks:

```
long thisFileSize;
using (Stream thisFileStream = File.OpenRead(fullPathToFile))
    thisFileSize = thisFileStream.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need open file and to know its size throgh GetFileSize function.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way, added FileShare parameter, even file is using, still can open for get length.

```
using var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
size = fs.Length;
fs.Close();
```